# UITests-How to get current language in UITests

Tags: ios, objective-c, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init]; 
[app.buttons[@"login"] tap];
```

See as above, in tests.m file, I want get login button by string "login", But, my app support multi-languages. How to get current language of my app.

The method below is the method how I get current Language. User set language in setting view of my app. I store current Language in NSUserDefaults.

```
+ (NSString*)currentLanguage 
{
    NSUserDefaults *lanUser = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *currentLanguage = [lanUser valueForKey:kCNOGASingularLanguage];
    if([currentLanguage length]==0)
        currentLanguage = kApplicationLanguageEnglish;
    return currentLanguage;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to test if the app is properly localized of are you trying to test the functionality regardless of the language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing the user's language in your app's `UserDefaults` and then accessing that from your UITest won't work. Your app and the UITest are running as separate processes, which means that your UITest cannot access your app's `UserDefaults`

There is a simple solution: To become independent from the users language you can set the `accessibilityIdentifier` on your `UIButton` and then access the button via the `accessibilityIdentifier`:

**In your app:**

```
button.accessibilityIdentifier = @"login";
```

**In your UITest:**

```
[app.buttons[@"login"] tap];
```

The accessibilityIdentifier is never displayed and `VoiceOver` also does not read it, so it does not have to be localized. Just make sure you are using `accessibilityIdentifier` and **not** `accessibilityLabel`. Because `accessibilityLabel` will be read by `VoiceOver` for handicapped users and should be localized.

**ALTERNATIVE**

If you cannot use `accessibilityIdentifier` to query your UI elements you could use your app's `LocalizableStrings` file in your UITests to get the localized button title (in this case):

First add your `Localizable.strings` file to your UITest target, then access the file via the UITest bundle to get the localized strings (I use a little helper method for that):

```
func localized(_ key: String) -> String {
    let uiTestBundle = Bundle(for: AClassFromYourUITests.self)
    return NSLocalizedString(key, bundle: uiTestBundle, comment: "")
}
```

I wrote a little [blog post](https://www.pixeldock.com/blog/how-to-use-your-localizable-strings-in-your-xcode-uitests/) about this a while back with some more details.

Comment: Thank you joern, But There are many places should set accessibilityIdentifier in original codes. Do you have other methods that no need to change original codes.

Comment: If you really have to you could use your LocalizableStrings file in your UITests to get the localized Button title. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your detail answer! But the problem is I do not use Localizable.strings file. I just create two plist language files then get text by key like this: [CMMultiLanguage stringMultiLanguageWithIdentity:@"key"];

Comment: Then `accessibilityIdentifier' is the way to go.